# PC Stucking on windows logo even in format drive

Tags: windows, boot, bsod

I built a new pc with the best parts. Now I can't run it. Here is the story, parts, and what I tried:

### Problem

I can't boot pc even in format drive. It is stuck on the windows logo after 5 secs. Sometimes it's passing the windows logo part, and the format view is coming. But after than throwing an error named `CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT`.
There is a [video of problem.](https://www.veed.io/view/e11ced65-d7f7-4f1d-9ebd-b0534920bdb3?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

### Weirdly successful solution

If I install a Live Linux USB, and run this USB with `acpi=off` configuration, pc is opening. Otherwise, it never opens.

### What I tried

- Clear rams, run memtests on them
- Sent motherboard to warranty, its fine
- Check SSD on another pc
- Try every bios configuration, including the default one
- Test W10, W11 usbs (officially created with original windows media creation tools)

### Parts

- MSI PRO B760M-A WIFI
- Intel Core i7 13700K 13th Gen
- ASUS GeForce TUF RTX 3060 V2 OC 12GB
- Samsung 980 PRO M.2 SSD 500GB
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 32 GB (2x16) RAM 3600MHZ
- Seasonic FOCUS 650W 80+ GOLD
- MSI Mag CoreLiquid B240M

UPDATE:
There is only one solution if this problem occurs on you too: send cpu to intel.

Comment: (1) Try updating BIOS (UEFI) and (2) get a statement from the manufacturer that the board properly supports Windows 10 and 11  (UEFI, GPT, Secure Boot and TPM V2 for Windows 11 and best for Windows 10)

Comment: Hi @John thanks for your time.
1- BIOS is using latest version. 2- Every part supports both w10 and w11

Comment: Can you try with fewer components:  1 memory chip, can you run for a very short time without the liquid cooler, remove wireless card if you can.  See if you can at least get it to start.

Comment: 1 memory chip: result is same. Short time without liqud: cannot because motherboard not allow me to do that. Wireless card is built-in.

Comment: I am not sure what else to suggest at this point. Check your build for short circuits to ground on the main board standoffs.

Comment: Also make sure any cards are perfectly aligned and seated

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Also i recorded a video about that: https://www.veed.io/view/e11ced65-d7f7-4f1d-9ebd-b0534920bdb3?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

Comment: I could not come up with anything new.

Comment: Try without the Nvidia graphics card (the CPU has integrated graphics). If successful then install as usual and later try adding the graphics card.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto thanks for your time. I already unplug graphic card and started to run pc with only these components: cpu, cooler, ram, format usb. Didn't work.

Comment: If the symptom was the exact same then try another USB, preferably (and unfortunately) USB2.0; try another USB stick. Other than this either you have an incorrect setting in UEFI - if it stills allows Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode make sure to disable it to assure you're booting in UEFI mode or something else - or you have a defective motherboard even if it work with Linux (the `acpi=off` parameter you say you needed to use suggests this might be the case).